# Dataflow expression builder greatest max integer ADF

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-synapse

I am using data factory's expression builder to build dataflows (Aggregrate Function) to 1. group movies by year, 2.find the max rating of movies 3. Return movie title for max.

I have already grouped by year so I'm trying to return something like

```
max(toInteger(Rating)) or greatest(toInteger(Rating))
```

and also get the 'title' of the movie that is max, can this be done in expression builder?

Answer (score 1):

The Aggregate transformation defines aggregations of columns in your data streams. Using the Expression Builder, you can define different types of aggregations such as SUM, MIN, **MAX**, and COUNT **grouped by existing or computed columns.**

I tried to repro the issue with sample data and I can observe that getting the movie title isn't possible in Aggregate function in mapping data flow.

[image]

In `Data preview` we can see we are only getting group by column and aggregate column. There is no option to include movie name column here.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. I've tried to created branches from the source, grouping by year. Group1 (like above) with year and max rating Group2 with movie title and maxrating. However the years are not grouped. Ultimately this comes down to trying to return a string value in an aggregate function in the expression builder

Comment: 'Columns should be wrapped with aggregate function' is the error I get when trying to return a string within an aggregate function

Comment: You need to use an aggregate function always in an aggregate expression. Wrap the string value inside something like last(). ie. last(title)